# Getting task order and rearranging in Asana API

Tags: asana

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to receive the order of the tasks in an Asana project?
2. More importantly, is there a way to rearrange tasks order in a project, via the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can reorder tasks in a project using the `addProject` API call (and the `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` properties). See https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#projects for more information.

Answer (score 0):

(I work at Asana)

Currently tasks are returned in project priority order. Completed tasks may be interleaved, but you can identify them because they have `completed: true`. There is not currently a way to change the order of the tasks in a project via the API, but it's something we will add in the future.

Comment: Any update on this? Its going to be 2 years now! We really need this feature as we work a lot with sections and there is no way to differentiate between tasks and sections.

Comment: I'm sorry you're blocked on this feature! I don't have a material update and can't commit to anything, but this work actually recently bubbled up on our roadmap for "soon". That means possibly in the next 2-3 months. If not by that time, we may have a better idea of how much farther out it is then. Either way, thanks for voting for this feature! It helps us prioritize, even if we don't always seem to be prioritizing in your favor. :/